# RTrim not working in sql server 2005-2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Looked over the net but could find a solution

Could anybody tell me why the following would not work?Am I missing the obvious!!

```
SELECT RTRIM('99999        ')
```

You cannot see very well from above after 99999 I have many empty spaces.

My column contains numbers and I could do

```
SELECT LEFT(Myfield, 8)
```

and this would work but I don't know the length of the column.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: When I do : `SELECT '[' + RTRIM('99999        ')  + ']'` I do get `[99999]` as the output - so the `RTRIM` ***does*** indeed work. What's your issue? You haven't really explained that very well ....

Comment: thanks for your reply .Sorry if I have not explained well.Are you saying that if you do SELECT RTRIM('99999    ') it trims for you?

Comment: Sure it does - see my `SELECT` - I'm surrounding the result with square brackets. It just simply works (at least on my SQL Server 2012 instance)

Comment: I'm guessing that you're placing the *result* of this RTRIM into a `char(x)` column or variable (rather than `varchar(x)`). If so, you cannot prevent the padding being reintroduced.

Answer (score 1):

For `Rtrim` you can use

```
Declare @temp varchar(100)
Set @temp = '99999       '

Select Rtrim(@temp)
```

Output:= 99999